# Can all UDFs be set to volatile globally?

Tags: vba, excel

I have several functions like:

```
function testXYZ(rng as range)

doSomething()

end function
```

I want the functions to be recalculated every time any value in the sheet changes, so I've changed them individually to:

```
function testXYZ(rng as range)

Application.Volatile     
doSomething()

end function
```

Is there a way to set `Application.Volatile` globally, or does it have to be done on a function-by-function basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be done on a function-by-function basis, but you might want to consider setting Workbook.ForceFullCalculation to True instead. 
This will have the effect of making every recalculation recalculate every single formula  including your functions. Of course this will also make your calculations slower in the same way as Application.Volatile does.
You can do this in the Workbook_Open event